# Using Eloquent methods with Sentry

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, cartalyst-sentry

I'm using Sentry with my Laravel app, and I'm wondering if it's possible to make use of some of the great Eloquent methods while using Sentry to manage my User objects.  For example, with Eloquent I can look up a user, and create one if they don't exist, like this:

```
$user = User::firstOrNew(array('email'=>'email@example.com'));
```

I would like to accomplish the same thing with Sentry, but from what I can tell, it can't be done out of the box.  Instead, I would have to handle an exception like this:

```
 try{
     $user = Sentry::findUserByLogin('email@example.com');
 }
 catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e){
     $user = Sentry::createUser(array(
         'email' => 'email@example.com'
     ));
 }
```

The Eloquent method is cleaner and less work, so I'm wondering if there is any way to do that with Sentry.

Comment: You can extend `Santry` class and add/override the method.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
$user = Sentry::getEmptyUser()->firstOrCreate(array('email'=>'email@example.com'));
```